# How to populate an array with a data from a function?

Tags: arrays, json, swift

Hello I have the following function:

```
 func parceDosi()
{

    struct City{

        let name : String
      //  let location : CLLocation

    }

    var cities = [City]()


    var person = "Person"
    let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    let ReadableJSON = JSON ( data:jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil )

    NumberRows = ReadableJSON ["People"].count

    for (var i = 0 ; i <= NumberRows; i++ )
    {
        Person += "\(i)"

        let NameImeNaObekt = ReadableJSON ["People"] [Person] ["B1"].string as String!

        let NameShirina = ReadableJSON ["People"] [Person] ["C1"].string as String!

        let NameDuljina = ReadableJSON ["People"] [Person] ["D1"].string as String!

        let latitude    =   (NameShirina as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude   =   (NameDuljina as NSString).doubleValue
   //     let loc         =  CLLocation( latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    //    let ci          =  City(name: NameImeNaObekt, location: loc)

        let ci    =  City( name: NameImeNaObekt)

        cities.append(ci)
```

which reads information from a json file. The information which is read I want to return it into a

var data =  [??]

this variable data works fine if it is in the following way:

var data =  [New York, Boston, California] ,

but in stead of writing New York, Boston, California , I want to return the function 
       func parceDosi(),
       because all of the cities are parsed there from a json file and I do not have to write every single one.Do you have an idea how to do that, I am new and something in my syntaxis is wrong.
Here is the JSON File:

```
  {
      "People": {
        "Person0": {
            "A1": "Безплатен Сок",
            "B1": "Царево 11",
            "C1": "43.0757",
            "D1": "23.6172",
            "E1": "http://weknowyourdreams.com/image.php?pic=/images/beer/beer-07.jpg"
                   },

        "Person1": {
            "A1": "Безплатна Бира",
            "B1": "Царево 22",
            "C1": "44.0757",
            "D1": "24.6172",
            "E1": "http://weknowyourdreams.com/image.php?pic=/images/beer/beer-07.jpg"
                    },
"Person2": {
    "A1": "Безплатен Десерт",
    "B1": "Царево 33",
    "C1": "45.0757",
    "D1": "25.6172",
    "E1": "http://weknowyourdreams.com/image.php?pic=/images/beer/beer-07.jpg"
},
"Person3": {
    "A1": "Безплатно Кафе",
    "B1": "Царево 55",
    "C1": "41.0757",
    "D1": "21.6172",
    "E1": "http://weknowyourdreams.com/image.php?pic=/images/beer/beer-07.jpg"
},
"Person4": {
    "A1": "Безплатна Кола",
    "B1": "Царево 66",
    "C1": "46.0757",
    "D1": "26.6172",
    "E1": "http://weknowyourdreams.com/image.php?pic=/images/beer/beer-07.jpg"


    }
  }
  }
```

Comment: You haven't declare struct properly it will out side the function not inside and from your previous question city name contains by key `A1` not `B1`. Also there is not data variable in your code.

Comment: would you please show me what is the right declaration?

Comment: The code is very hard to read. Variable names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter to not getting confused with classes and structs whose names are supposed to start with a capital letter.

Comment: I am sorry for that, I started with swift a month ago and I am still a beginner, but in stead of criticise me I would be glad to to learn something new, by correcting my code with the right one.

Comment: I criticised you for your own benefit. The more legible code you write the more and faster answers you get. Besides you learned already something new doing that ;-)

Comment: PS: Another *new* thing: The recommended syntax to unwrap optionals is `as! Type` rather than `as Type!` and you can help the community by showing the JSON or at least the relevant part to be parsed.

Comment: I have added the JSON file and I would be glad if someone provide me with an example or solution,because someone has deleted the answer provided me from another user.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Person` in the JSON contains 5 key-value pairs so I extended the struct `City`, the property `location` will be created from latitude and longitude:

```
struct City {
  let name : String
  let city : String
  let location : CLLocation
  let imageURL : NSURL
}
```

Since you're using SwiftJSON the parsing is quite clearly arranged

```
var cities = [City]()

func parceDosi() {
  guard let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("jsonFile", withExtension: "json"), jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
    print("Error finding JSON File")
    return
  }

  let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData) // the mutable option is not needed.

  let people = readableJSON["People"].dictionaryValue
  for (_, person) in people {
    let personName = person["A1"].stringValue
    let cityName = person["B1"].stringValue
    let latitude = person["C1"].doubleValue
    let longitude = person["D1"].doubleValue
    let imageURL = person["E1"].stringValue

    let city = City(name: personName, city: cityName, location: CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude), imageURL: NSURL(string:imageURL)!)
    cities.append(city)
  }

  // This is an example to get the nearest city from a given location

  let myLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 50.0, longitude: 8.0)
  let nearestlocations = cities.sort { (city1, city2) -> Bool in
    return city1.location.distanceFromLocation(myLocation) < city2.location.distanceFromLocation(myLocation)
  }
  print(nearestlocations.first!)
}
```

PS: As you are responsible for the JSON file in the bundle, I recommend to use an array for the people (rather than a dictionary) and give the "chessboard"-keys more descriptive names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the professional code!! I really appreciate it and will learn it. According to your code I can see that you return all of the 5-key values. In my application I will also need to compare the the user's current location with the other locations from the JSON file. Would you advice me how to compare that?

Comment: I updated the answer adding some code to get the nearest city from a given location.

Comment: would you please show me how to display your values on Table View Cell. I created a new Table View Controller and Table View cells, shall I send it to you or you can understand me?